# Windows ReportViewer Export to Excel(2013) is Removing Hyperlinks

Tags: .net, windows, excel, hyperlink, reportviewer

I am receiving this message when exporting a report to Excel using the built in excel export in Windows ReportViewer.

"Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.
Removed Feature: Hyperlinks from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"

There are two columns in the report that have Text with a hyperlink in the report and work correctly in the report. However, when exporting to Excel(2013) the error message above pops up and the hyperlinks are removed from the spreadsheet.  Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a limitation of Excel format (in my own experience it really was):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

> Hyperlinks in a worksheet: 66,530 hyperlinks

So the only solution in this case is to reduce number of hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem. Our excel sheet contains about 100 000 rows and one of the column is for the document code and it's an hyperlink to web application. We receives the Removed Feature: Hyperlinks message also. We are trying to found a solution to fix this issue for our client. Our excels are generated in .NET 4.5 with EPPlus SDK.

For now, its seems the problem occurs when the number of rows is over 65 536.

It would be great if someone can help us on this.

Comment: An issue has been created for this by someone on EPPlus codeplex website. https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14949

Comment: This type of information is better as a comment on the question or as a new question.

Comment: Given the circumstances, you will have better luck getting an answer if you post this as a new question.